# Abstract Class with Generic Subtype

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overriding, abstract-class

I implemented an abstract class like the following:

```
public abstract class Pack
{
    protected List<PackEntry> m_Entries;

    public Int32 EntriesCount
    {
        get { return m_Entries.Count; }
    }

    public Pack()
    {
        m_Entries = new List<PackEntry>();
    }

    #region Methods: Abstract
    ...
    #endregion
}

public sealed class PackTypeA : Pack { ... }
public sealed class PackTypeB : Pack { ... }
```

And a `PackEntry` subclass also:

```
public abstract class PackEntry
{
    protected Byte[] m_Data;

    protected PackEntry() { }

    public Byte[] GetData()
    {
        return m_Data;
    }

    public void SetData(Byte[] data)
    {
        m_Data = data;
    }

    #region Methods: Abstract
    ...
    #endregion
}

public sealed class PackEntryTypeA : PackEntry { ... }
public sealed class PackEntryTypeB : PackEntry { ... }
```

This means that the derived class `PackTypeA` will use `PackEntryTypeA` entries and `PackTypeB` will use `PackEntryTypeB` and so on.
Now... I'm using my `Pack` abstract class as in the following code snippet:

```
Pack pack = useTypeA ? new PackTypeA() : new PackTypeB();
pack.AbstractMethod1();

if (condition)
    pack.AbstractMethod2();

...
```

Everything works like a charm but inside `AbstractMethod1()` ... `AbstractMethodN()` overrides I'm working a lot with the entries list. Which needs a lot of casting like:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < m_Entries.Count; ++i)
{
    PackEntryTypeA entry = (PackEntryTypeA)m_Entries[i];
    ...
```

It's getting tedious. So I tried the following approach implementing a generic type to my `Pack` class:

```
public abstract class Pack<T> where T : PackEntry
{
    protected List<T> m_Entries;

    public Int32 EntriesCount
    {
        get { return m_Entries.Count; }
    }

    public Pack()
    {
        m_Entries = new List<T>();
    }

    #region Methods: Abstract
    ...
    #endregion
}

public sealed class PackTypeA : Pack<PackEntryTypeA> { ... }
public sealed class PackTypeB : Pack<PackEntryTypeB> { ... }
```

Which is much, much, much better! But the problem is that I can't use the following code snippet anymore:

```
Pack pack = useTypeA ? new PackTypeA() : new PackTypeB();
```

Because it requires the generic type to be specified (which I really can't):

```
Pack<PackTypeN>
```

The last solution I figured out is to move the list to the derived classes but it's not very elegant. Can someone kindly point me to a solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pack<PackEntryTypeA>` and `Pack<PackEntryTypeB>` are different types, so, to be able to store them in a same variable they have to have same base class or interface.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var pack = 1 == 1 ? (IPack)new PackTypeA() : (IPack)new PackTypeB();
    pack.AbstractMethod1();
    pack = 1 == 2 ? (IPack)new PackTypeA() : (IPack)new PackTypeB();
    pack.AbstractMethod1();
}

public interface IPack { void AbstractMethod1(); }

public abstract class PackEntry { }

public sealed class PackEntryTypeA : PackEntry {}
public sealed class PackEntryTypeB : PackEntry {}

public abstract class Pack<T> : IPack where T : PackEntry
{
    protected List<T> m_Entries = new List<T>();
    public abstract void AbstractMethod1();
}

public sealed class PackTypeA : Pack<PackEntryTypeA> 
{
    public override void AbstractMethod1() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(m_Entries.GetType().ToString());
    }
}

public sealed class PackTypeB : Pack<PackEntryTypeB> 
{
    public override void AbstractMethod1() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(m_Entries.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PackEntryTypeA]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PackEntryTypeB]
```